# Sleep during stream processing in Spring integration sftp

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I use Spring integration sftp to get data and parse and send to target. But the streaming is too fast, like every second, there will be tens of thousands of lines sent to target. But the target system can not handle too much data in a short time.

Now I want to make it slower. Is there any way like sleep, or other that I can control the speed of streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a `RateLimiterRequestHandlerAdvice` can help you with that: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/handler-advice.html#rate-limiter-advice

Although it would be great to see what is your process...

> the streaming is too fast

Sounds like you shift your polling to some `TaskExecutor`, so your consumer can't keep up with incoming messages. Probably you can limit a rate with sufficient thread pool. Or you can increase a polling interval. Consider do not use a `fixedRate` for the poller also: you won't spawn more polling task than you need. With a `fixedDelay` you won't have more polling tasks than 1 and a new one won't be spawn until the previous is finished.

Comment: Thanks, I use fixedDelay now. My scenario is, I got every csv file from sftp, parse every line to json and send to server. If one csv file is too large, like about 50,000 lines. It will be parsed in almost 1 or 2 seconds. But my server can not handle that many requests. So event I set a longer time with fixedDelay, but for one file, it is too fast. And I also didn't use TaskExecutor. It looks like it polls the file one by one.  And I tried the limiter, and it works. Thanks.